# How does sudo determine what environment variables to preserve, not preserve, and check?

Tags: centos, sudo

OS: CentOS 7.7
sudo: sudo-1.8.23-4.el7_7.1.x86_64

Running "sudo -V" as root gives you, among other things, lists of environment variables that are preserved, not preserved, and checked (presumably) during user changes. For example, switching from user joe.smith to dave.jones or root.

My question is: How are these lists generated?

I'm assuming part of it comes from the Defaults set in the sudoers file, but there are far more environment variables listed by "sudo -V" than are listed as Defaults in my sudoers file.

```
$ sudo sudo -V
...
Environment variables to preserve:
        STONAVM_HOME
        HOME
        EDITOR
        XAUTHORIZATION
        XAUTHORITY
        PS2
        PS1
        PATH
        LS_COLORS
        KRB5CCNAME
        HOSTNAME
        DISPLAY
        COLORS


$ sudo grep Default /etc/sudoers
Defaults umask=0027
Defaults env_keep+="EDITOR HOME STONAVM_HOME"
Defaults!FULL_PROMISC noexec
```

The one that's driving me nuts is KRB5CCNAME and despite finding the following bug:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1324486

I don't even think that affects us because we're not using sssd for sudoers. This host does not have a sudoers entry in /etc/nsswitch.conf.

Happy to post any other configs necessary to track this down.

Comment: What does `/etc/environment` contain?

Comment: /etc/environment is empty